Is it possible to buy an international bus ticket online from Singapore to JB Sentral?
I'm looking for a way to buy a bus ticket online that I board in Singapore and disembark in JB Sentral. I will use it as proof of onward travel when I board my flight to Singapore so a bus that only takes me to the Singapore end of the Causeway is probably not going to work.
The one that seems to definitely cross the border is the "Causeway Link Singapore Cross-Border Bus", but either the website is broken or it's just so confusing that I can't work it out.
For "origin" I can select from three places in Singapore: Jurong East, Harbour Front, and Queen Street. For "destination" there is "City", plus three places in KL and Malacca. This may or may not mean that "City" is Johor Bahru, but if I select it, and any of the three origins, I just get this error:

Is there a way to get this site to work and sell me a ticket from somewhere in Singapore to JB Sentral?
If not, is there another website that will sell me a ticket online in advance for a bus that will cross the border and drop me off in JB Sentral?

Do you need to take a bus? Another option would be to take the Woodlands/JB shuttle train. Tickets are available from KTMB's website. Sometimes they sell out, but if you precisely want to buy in advance, this could be a good option.
Despite crossing a border, Singapore to JB is basically a local bus, and tickets are usually bought upon boarding in cash or with EZLink, not in advance.
Note that bus or train tickets to JB only cost a few SGD. Generally speaking, travelers with western passports are not given a whole lot of scrutiny at Singapore immigration, and, if you even get asked, just saying "I plan to continue by land to Malaysia" without a pre-bought ticket will be okay. However, if you do attract scrutiny, a S$5 ticket is not likely to be wildly impressive evidence of your plan to use it, and either having one or not having one will not matter much.

For now I'm comparing the pros and cons of the train and bus options. I've asked another question about KTMB. For proof of onward travel I have no choice but to buy in advance. Scoot always asks me to show proof before they let me board my flight over the past 5 years or more. I don't think Singapore immigration has ever asked me.

How about bus from Singapore to Melacca/KL as proof of travel? It will cost bit, but works the same and availability is not an issue.
